Form checkbox validating 2 questions with no defined 'group'
Using a third party so I cannot amend any of the form html itself, and yes they are all checkboxes  (as much as I wish they were radio buttons), the names / ids are all different and can't be changed, nor can any divs be added to wrap around the checkboxes to add a class to. The form itself has checkboxes laid out into two questions (but aren't grouped and so all are individual & unique).
I need to target the checkboxes and ensure that one is selected from both questions when the Opt Out checkbox isn't checked, and then shows a "You need to select at least one topic and one entity." message if one or the other isn't.
Newsletters, Webinars, Events, Surveys - all are the first group
A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K - are all the second group
I've tried using groups but that expects you to be able to wrap a div around the two questions, so that won't work. I was thinking an If statement that checks the first 4, and then checks the other 11, but I could not figure out how to make that work. I'm fairly new to JS so I really don't know what I'm doing! Form code below.
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" class="form" id="form">
    <p class="form-field  email pd-text required">
        <label class="field-label" for="1003331_1003331_67620">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="1003331_1003331_67620" id="1003331_1003331_67620" value="" class="text" size="30"
            maxlength="255" onchange="" onfocus="">
    </p>
    <div id="error_for_1003331_1003331_67620" style="display:none"></div>
    <div class="to0cs">To0cs:</div>
    <p class="form-field to0cs OPTIN_Newsletters pd-checkbox     ">
        <label class="field-label" for="1003331_678600_1003331_67860">Newsletters</label>
        <span class="value"><span><input type="checkbox" name="1003331_678600_1003331_67860_872067"
                    id="1003331_678600_1003331_67860" value="872067" onchange=""></span></span>
    </p>
    <div id="error_for_1003331_678600_1003331_67860" style="display:none"></div>

    <p class="form-field  OPTIN_Events pd-checkbox     ">

        <label class="field-label" for="1003331_678630_1003331_67863">Events</label>

        <span class="value"><span><input type="checkbox" name="1003331_678630_1003331_67863_872070"
                    id="1003331_678630_1003331_67863" value="872070" onchange=""></span></span>

    </p>
    <div id="error_for_1003331_678630_1003331_67863" style="display:none"></div>
    <p class="form-field p-top OPTIN_Webinars pd-checkbox     ">

        <label class="field-label" for="1003331_678660_1003331_67866">Webinars</label>


        <span class="value"><span><input type="checkbox" name="1003331_678660_1003331_67866_872073"
                    id="1003331_678660_1003331_67866" value="872073" onchange=""></span></span>

        <span class="description">Entities:</span>

    </p>
    <div id="error_for_1003331_678660_1003331_67866" style="display:none"></div>


    <p class="form-field p-top pb-4 OPTIN_A pd-checkbox     ">

        <label class="field-label" for="1003331_678690_1003331_67869">Surveys</label>


        <span class="value"><span><input type="checkbox" name="1003331_678690_1003331_67869_872076"
                    id="1003331_678690_1003331_67869" value="872076" onchange=""></span></span>

    </p>
    <div id="error_for_1003331_678690_1003331_67869" style="display:none"></div>


    <p class="form-field spacer OPTIN_B pd-checkbox     ">

        <label class="field-label" for="1003331_676230_1003331_67623">BBF</label>


        <span class="value"><span><input type="checkbox" name="1003331_676230_1003331_67623_870732"
                    id="1003331_676230_1003331_67623" value="870732" onchange=""></span></span>

    </p>
    <div id="error_for_1003331_676230_1003331_67623" style="display:none"></div>


    <p class="form-field spacer OPTIN_C pd-checkbox     ">

        <label class="field-label" for="1003331_676260_1003331_67626">BBI</label>


        <span class="value"><span><input type="checkbox" name="1003331_676260_1003331_67626_870735"
                    id="1003331_676260_1003331_67626" value="870735" onchange=""></span></span>

    </p>
    <div id="error_for_1003331_676260_1003331_67626" style="display:none"></div>


    <p class="form-field p-top OPTIN_D pd-checkbox     ">

        <label class="field-label" for="1003331_678720_1003331_67872">BYCN-IT</label>


        <span class="value"><span><input type="checkbox" name="1003331_678720_1003331_67872_872079"
                    id="1003331_678720_1003331_67872" value="872079" onchange=""></span></span>

    </p>
    <div id="error_for_1003331_678720_1003331_67872" style="display:none"></div>


    <p class="form-field p-top OPTIN_E pd-checkbox     ">

        <label class="field-label" for="1003331_678750_1003331_67875">BYCN Matériel</label>


        <span class="value"><span><input type="checkbox" name="1003331_678750_1003331_67875_872082"
                    id="1003331_678750_1003331_67875" value="872082" onchange=""></span></span>

    </p>
    <div id="error_for_1003331_678750_1003331_67875" style="display:none"></div>


    <p class="form-field p-top OPTIN_F pd-checkbox     ">

        <label class="field-label" for="1003331_678780_1003331_67878">BYCN-SA</label>


        <span class="value"><span><input type="checkbox" name="1003331_678780_1003331_67878_872085"
                    id="1003331_678780_1003331_67878" value="872085" onchange=""></span></span>

    </p>
    <div id="error_for_1003331_678780_1003331_67878" style="display:none"></div>


    <p class="form-field p-top OPTIN_G pd-checkbox     ">

        <label class="field-label" for="1003331_678810_1003331_67881">BYTP</label>


        <span class="value"><span><input type="checkbox" name="1003331_678810_1003331_67881_872088"
                    id="1003331_678810_1003331_67881" value="872088" onchange=""></span></span>

    </p>
    <div id="error_for_1003331_678810_1003331_67881" style="display:none"></div>


    <p class="form-field p-top OPTIN_H pd-checkbox     ">

        <label class="field-label" for="1003331_678840_1003331_67884">BYUK</label>


        <span class="value"><span><input type="checkbox" name="1003331_678840_1003331_67884_872091"
                    id="1003331_678840_1003331_67884" value="872091" onchange=""></span></span>

    </p>
    <div id="error_for_1003331_678840_1003331_67884" style="display:none"></div>


    <p class="form-field p-top OPTIN_I pd-checkbox     ">

        <label class="field-label" for="1003331_678870_1003331_67887">Dragages Hong Kong</label>


        <span class="value"><span><input type="checkbox" name="1003331_678870_1003331_67887_872094"
                    id="1003331_678870_1003331_67887" value="872094" onchange=""></span></span>

    </p>
    <div id="error_for_1003331_678870_1003331_67887" style="display:none"></div>


    <p class="form-field p-top pb-5 opt-spacer OPTIN_J pd-checkbox     ">

        <label class="field-label" for="1003331_678900_1003331_67890">Losinger Marazzi</label>


        <span class="value"><span><input type="checkbox" name="1003331_678900_1003331_67890_872097"
                    id="1003331_678900_1003331_67890" value="872097" onchange=""></span></span>

    </p>
    <div id="error_for_1003331_678900_1003331_67890" style="display:none"></div>


    <p class="form-field p-top pb-5 opt-spacer OPTIN_K pd-checkbox     ">

        <label class="field-label" for="1003331_678930_1003331_67893">VSL</label>


        <span class="value"><span><input type="checkbox" name="1003331_678930_1003331_67893_872100"
                    id="1003331_678930_1003331_67893" value="872100" onchange=""></span></span>

    </p>
    <div id="error_for_1003331_678930_1003331_67893" style="display:none"></div>


    <div class="opt">If you no longer wish to receive communications from the company, you can
        unsubscribe from all communications by checking the box below:</div>
    <p class="form-field opt msg opted_out pd-checkbox   no-label  ">


        <span class="value"><span><input type="checkbox" name="1003331_684720_1003331_68472_877884"
                    id="1003331_684720_1003331_68472_877884" value="877884" onchange=""><label class="inline"
                    for="1003331_684720_1003331_68472_877884">I no longer wish to
                    receive communications from the company</label></span></span>

    </p>
    <div id="error_for_1003331_684720_1003331_68472" style="display:none"></div>

    <p style="position:absolute; width:190px; left:-9999px; top: -9999px;visibility:hidden;">
        <label for="0_extra_field">Comments</label>
        <input type="text" name="0_extra_field" id="0_extra_field">
    </p>


    <!-- forces IE5-8 to correctly submit UTF8 content  -->
    <input name="_utf8" type="hidden" value="☃">

    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" accesskey="s" value="Save my preferences">
    </p>
</form>

